# Magento 2 Custom Email Template

Tags: magento2, module, email-templates

I have created New Custom Header Template from admin.

This email template i want to use in my custom email template in custom module.

Currently i am using this below code to add header.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
```

[image]

So now how can i add my custom created template as shown in above image instead of this default header, can any one guide me for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps.

[image]

[image]

You can check your new template value in DB using below given QUERY

> SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'design/email/header_template'

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Its working, thanks @kishan, I really appreciate your help.